# Php loop create array inside php code

Tags: php

I need some help with the following code...

How do I create the array from a mysql db:

I have already created the connection set: I want to get the data for my domain from the db, this I can do - My problem is mainly how to create the loop...

```
<?php
// Each sponsor is an element of the $sponsors array:
$sponsors = array( 
    array('domain1.com','The biggest social network in the world.','http://domain1.com/'),
    array('domain2.com','Imaging and optical technology manufacturer.','http://domain2.com/'));
// Randomizing the order of sponsors:
shuffle($sponsors);
?>
```

I have tried to do it like this:

```
do {
array(''.$row_rs_domainrecord['g_sites_image'].'','The biggest social network in the world.',''.$row_rs_domainrecord['g_sites_url'].''),
} while ($row_rs_domainrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_domainrecord)););
```

but get an error here

But are not getting the results and get an error `$sponsors = array(`

What would be the easiest way to greate this loop?

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting, and what exactly are you trying to do? Sorry, not clear on both counts from your question.

Comment: Also, `''.$row[...].''` is nonsense, it's the same as `$row[...]`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DO, expecting ')' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\domain\index.php on line 68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're looking for this:

```
$sponsors = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_domainrecord)) {
    $sponsors[] = array($row['g_sites_image'], 'The biggest social network in the world.', $row['g_sites_url']);
}
```

`$array[] =` *appends* to an existing array.

Comment: Thanks Deceze - The solutions works perfectly - I envisage that I am going to do this frequently and this will help alot!

Answer (score 2):

```
$sponser = array();
while ($row_rs_domainrecord = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_domainrecord))
{
   $sponser[] = array($row_rs_domainrecord['g_sites_image'],'The biggest social network in the world.',$row_rs_domainrecord['g_sites_url']);
}
```